# Can a Starly inherit a Staravia/Staraptor's Hidden Ability once it evolves?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I just noticed Starly doesn't have a Hidden Ability, but its evolutions, Staravia and Staraptor, do.

So if I were to breed a female Staravia/Staraptor correctly (not using a Ditto), would the offspring Starly have a 60% chance of evolving into a Staravia that knows its species's hidden ability, Reckless, even though it would just have Keen Eye as a Starly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you breed a female Reckless Staravia, there's a chance you'll get a Starly with its hidden ability from the egg, when it evolves.

You can check to see if has it by using 13 rare candies on it (reset and try again, if it does not).